# How do I add a key to my components, while getting the key prop warning in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am getting the key prop warning on my console and wanted to know what my approach should be:

I tried adding an id to my array and adding it to my template list component, but something doesnt seem right.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `TemplateList`. See react-warning-keys for more information.
    in TemplateCard (created by TemplateList)
    in TemplateList (created by ActionPageNew)
    in div (created by ActionPageNew)
    in div (created by ActionPageNew)
    in ActionPageNew (created by Onboarding)
    in div (created by Onboarding)
    in Onboarding
    in Route (created by PrivateRoute)
    in PrivateRoute
    in Outlet (created by Route)
    in Route (created by PrivateRoute)
    in PrivateRoute
    in Routes
    in div (created by App)
    in App
    in Router (created by HistoryRouter)
    in HistoryRouter
    in Provider
    in i
```

I added an id to my array objects like this:

```
    templates = [
        {
            title: "Grocery List",
            description: "Description of what this things does so the reader can have info of",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753993/groceries.png",
            id: 1,
        },

        {
            title: "Shopping Space",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png",
            id: 2,
        },

        {
            title: "Travel Planning",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753885/travel.png",
            id: 3,
        },

        {
            title: "Travel",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753993/groceries.png",
            id: 4,
        },
    ];
```

Then I have my Template List card component that maps and loops through the array:

In here I added key={item.id}

```
export type Template = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imgURL: string;
    id?: number;
};

type Props = {
    templates: Template[];
};

const TemplateList = ({ templates }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
            {templates.map((item) => (
                <TemplateCard
                    title={item.title}
                    description={item.description}
                    img={item.imgURL}
                    classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
                    key={item.id}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default TemplateList;
```

I do not know if this is the correct way, and where and what I should add to my TemplateCard component:

```
type Props = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    img: string;
    classNameToAdd?: string;
    classNameOnSelected?: string;
    id?: number;
};

const TemplateCard = ({ title, description, img, classNameToAdd, classNameOnSelected }: Props) => {
    const { aspectRatio, vmin } = useWindowResponsiveValues();
    let className = `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd}`;

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
    };

    if (selected) {
        className += `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd} ${classNameOnSelected}`;
    }

    return (
        <div style={card} className={className} onClick={handleClick}>
            <img style={imageSize} src={img}></img>
            <div style={cardTitle}>
                {title}
                {selected ? <BlueCheckIcon style={blueCheck} className={styles.blueCheck} /> : null}
            </div>
            <div style={descriptionCard}>{description}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

TemplateCard.defaultProps = {
    classNameOnSelected: styles.selected,
};

export default TemplateCard;
```

Comment: that is correct, you don't need to add anything to the component itself, the `key` prop is used by React internally

Comment: Yes it looks fine - you shouldn't be getting a key warning with that code AFAICT.

Comment: what version of react are you using? I simplified your code and don't get the warning in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5syn4pfr/

Comment: Thank you! 

 @superjisan, the error is indeed not appearing anymore, (I added ids to my array, and  key={item.id} to my templateCard loop ) I just wanted to check if I added the key correctly or if there was another better way to do this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `templates` array already has an `id` field for each element, I would use that as a key instead of indices, in case you may have to do filtering and sorting in the future.

Using indices as keys can be problematic when the UI involves filter and sorting because the index cannot uniquely identify each element in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is better if you add that id directly in the map like:

```
templates.map((item,index) => (
   <TemplateCard
      title={item.title}
      description={item.description}
      img={item.imgURL}
      classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
      key={`TemplateCard-${index}`}
   />
))
```

And then either pass it `TemplateCard` or wrap the TemplateCard in a div and assign the id to that.

Remember that the id should be unique that is why I'm adding the text before the index

Comment: The index can work as a key, but is not preferred in general unless the array itself has no unique fields. If the `templates` ends up involving filtering and sorting in the future (e.g. change of requirement), the index key will mess up the UI.